# Steady-state solution and initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, steady-state

Let's say that we have the following first order differential equation:
$$\frac{d \rho(t)}{d t}=F(\rho(t))$$
with some given initial condition $\rho(0)$.

I am interested in the steady-state solution $\rho_{ss}$, and to find it we set $\left.\frac{d\rho(t)}{d t}\right|_{t_{ss}}=0$ and solve the algebraic equation 
$$F(\rho_{ss})=0$$

However, how in this situation do we account for the initial condition $\rho(0)=\rho_0$, without solving the full differential equation? After solving the algebraic equation I get infinetely many solutions (actually two distinct solutions, but their superposition is also a solution).

P.s. I don't know if this helps, but in my case there is a conserved quantity $Q$, which is the same for $\rho(0)$ and $\rho_{ss}$.

Comment: Since the equation is a PDE, $\rho$ isn't function of only one variable, but of several. Do not write $\rho(t)$, but $\rho(t,?)$ and replace the "$?$" by the symbol of your other variable. Especially the notations $\rho(0)$ and $\rho_{ss}$ are ambiguous.

Comment: I changed it to ordinary differential equation.

Comment: Then, what is $\rho_{ss}$ ?

Comment: Actually I found the answer by myself. It indeed depends on the conserved quantity corresponding to the operator $\hat{Q}$. So we have the following additional equation: $\hat{Q}\rho(0)=\hat{Q}\rho_{ss}$, which determines the enique solution, based on the initial condition.

Comment: $\rho_{ss}$ is the steady-state solution.

Comment: What is the operator $Q$ ?

Comment: It is some operator that gives the conserved quantity $Q$. It is actually a functional.

Comment: Sorry, your question is fishy. We cannot help you without having the full information and without knowing exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: The question is fine, just forget the $Q$ thing. How do we account for the initial condition in the steady-state solution?

Comment: When you write $F\left(\rho(t)\right)$ what is known, what is unknown ?  Is $F(\rho)$ a known function or not ? Is $\rho(t)$ a known function or not ?

Comment: The function $F$ is known and the $\rho(t)$ is unknown (we are looking to find it).

Answer (score 3):

Solving the equation $\quad F(\rho)=0\quad $ gives $\rho_{ss}$, but doesn't gives the function $\rho(t)$. So we have to find the function $\rho(t)$ in which $\rho_0$ is a parameter.

$$\frac{d \rho(t)}{d t}=F(\rho(t))\quad\to\quad \frac{d\rho}{F(\rho)}=dt$$
$$\int \frac{d\rho}{F(\rho)}= t+c$$
$F(x)$ is a known function.

Suppose that it is possible to find an antiderivative for $\frac{1}{F(x)}$ , namely $G(x)$ , which then is a known function :
$$G(\rho)=t+c$$
$$\rho=G^{-1}(t+c)$$
where $\quad G^{-1}\quad$ is the inverse function of $G$.

\begin{cases}
\text{Initial point :} \quad G(\rho(0)) =0+c=c \quad\to\quad \rho= G^{-1}\left(t+G(\rho(0)) \right)\\
\text{Steady state point :} \quad \rho_{ss}=G^{-1}(t_{ss}+c)
\end{cases}
This leads to the relationship between $\rho_{ss}$ and $\rho_0=\rho(0)$ :
$$\rho_{ss}=G^{-1}\left(t_{ss}+G(\rho_0)\right)$$
where $G$ and $G^{-1}$ are known functions derived from the given function $F$.

$t_{ss}$ is a root of the equation $\quad F\left(\rho(t)\right)= F\left( G^{-1}\left(t+G(\rho_0)\right) \right)=0\quad$ where all functions are known.

Comment: Isn't this the same as solving the full differential equation $d\rho(t)/dt=F(\rho(t))$? Because otherwise how do you find the function $G$? What I asked is without solving the differential equation, which can be imposible to solve as in my case (I can solve only the steady-state algebraic equation $F(\rho(t_{ss}))=0$, and I want to account somehow for the initial condition $\rho(0)=\rho_0$).

Comment: For me, the problem is solved, anyways. If it is specified in the wording of the problem that it has to be solved without integrating the given function $\frac{1}{F}$, it is necessary to have the exact initial wording, word for word. Not a modified version. Because the function $F(\rho)$ depends on the initial condition. If $\rho_0$ changes, this is no longer exactly the same function. Necessarily $\rho_0$ is a parameter in the function $F$. To help you, we have to know where the given function $F$ comes from.

Comment: $F(\rho(t))$ doesn't depend on $\rho_0$. For example, $F(\rho(t))=\rho(t)+1$ or $F(\rho(t))=\rho^2(t)+1$, leading to differential equations $d\rho(t)/dt=\rho(t)+1$ or $d\rho(t)/dt=\rho^2(t)+1$ respectively.

Comment: What I mean is $F(t)=F(\rho(t))$ depends on $\rho_0$.

Comment: Note that in case of $F(\rho)=\rho+1$ never $\frac{d\rho}{dt}=0$, except in the trivial case $\rho_0=-1=\rho(t)=\rho_{ss}=$constant. Also in case of  $F(\rho)=\rho^2+1$ never  $\frac{d\rho}{dt}=0$ , so $\rho_{ss}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, right, the example that I gave don't have steady-state solution. But that't not the point. We suppose that our $F$ is such that the equation has steady-state solution. Also, the form of $F$ doesn't depend on the $\rho_0$. We don't know the $F(\rho(t))$, but only the form of $F$.

Comment: This is consistent with the solution  $F\left(\rho(t)\right)= F\left( G^{-1}\left(t+G(\rho_0)\right) \right)$ which shows how $F\left(\rho(t)\right)$ depends on $\rho_0$ .

Answer (score 1):

A steady state solution is a constant, that is, time-independent solution to the differential equation. So, if there is a steady state solution (let's call it $\rho_{ss}$), then it must be constant, and it must solve the differential equation. Because $\rho_{ss}$ is constant in time, we have $\frac{\text{d} \rho_{ss}}{\text{d} t} = 0$. Thus, because $\rho_{ss}$ must solve the differential equation, we know that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{d} \rho_{ss}}{\text{d} t} = 0 = F(\rho_{ss}) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
must be satisfied.

Looking again at equation $(1)$ from a slightly different perspective, we see that once we've found a value $x_*$ for which $F(x_*) = 0$, then $x_*$ is a steady state solution to our differential equation.

Steady state solutions are independent of time, so they have the same value for all time. So, *and this is important*, if you take your differential equation and you choose your initial value $\rho(0)$ to be *equal to* the stationary value $\rho_{ss}$, then the solution will *stay constant*.

On the other hand, if you choose an initial value $\rho(0)$ for which $F$ does not vanish, i.e. $F(\rho(0)) \neq 0$, then you will immediately start to move away from the initial value $\rho(0)$, because the initial velocity is nonzero: $\frac{\text{d} \rho}{\text{d} t}(0) = F(\rho(0)) \neq 0$.

So, if you choose your initial condition $\rho(0)$ just right (such that $F(\rho(0)) = 0$), then you've hit a steady state solution, and you'll stay on that steady state solution for all time.

Answer (score 0):

I am having some difficulty understanding the question, but I wanted to add some comments which were not addressed by previous responses.  As I understand you have a 1D ODE: $\rho' =  F(\rho)$ and you want to understand the steady states of $\rho$ as well as how initial conditions affect the steady states.  As you have said, the steady states are the solutions of $F(\rho)=0$, say $\{\rho_i\}_{i\in I}$. I will assume that these $\rho_i$ are somewhat well behaved (countable, isolated, etc).

Then, given any $\rho(0)$, we see that either $\rho(t) \rightarrow \rho_i$ for some $i$ or $\rho(t)\to \pm \infty$. To completely classify the behavior there are two cases:

Case 1: $\rho(0)=\rho_i$. This case is trivial and it is clear that $\rho(t)=\rho_i$ for all $t$.

Case 2: $\rho(0) \neq \rho_i$ for any $i$.  Here it can either happen that $\rho(t)\to \rho_i$, where $\rho_i$ is a stable equilibrium, or $\rho(t)\to \pm \infty$.

As an example consider $\rho' = \rho^2-1$. Plotting the graph of $\rho^2-1$ on the $\rho'$ vs $\rho$ plane reveals the entire picture (I apologize, I do not know how to include graphics here. I recommend reading Section 2.1 of Strogatz Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos if you are unfamiliar).  If $\rho(0)<1$ then $\rho(t) \to -1$. If $\rho(0)>1$ then $\rho(t) \to +\infty$. If $\rho(0)=1$ then $\rho(t)=1$ for all time. This is due to stability of the equilibrium point $\rho = -1$ and instability of $\rho=1$. That is, the interaction of initial conditions with equilibrium solutions depends on stability of the equilibria.